# In swift version 5.1.3 How is NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey used?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

Hi I am learning by watching the video. Since it was an old version, it seemed that you were using NS, but I don’t know how to use it now, so I ask

**Youtube video link**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKOswUE731c >> 32:40

```
let userEmailStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userEmail")
let userPasswordStored = NSUserDefulats.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userPassword")
```

In the current version, we know that you should use it without NS, but it is not used even if you subtract NS.
[Cannot be used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t06qu.png)

I would appreciate it if you let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UserDefaults` now and get the `String` values like this:

```
let userEmailStored = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userEmail")
let userPasswordStored = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userPassword")
```

You can use `UserDefaults` now and set the `String` values like this:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("email", forKey: "userEmail")
UserDefaults.standard.set("password", forKey: "userPassword")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to this, my problem was solved.

Comment: I pressed the upbutton, but Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Is displayed